# Disaster recovery preparation for DC

Tags: active-directory, domain-controller

I have a dc holding activedirectory, dns will be adding all infrastructure related services to this box (Dhcp, certificate server, terminal etc..)

I am not planning to replicate this as well, limited budget.

**Could you please share what you think i need to backup, in case server fails. Not just hardware but system fails?**

for hardware failure i think i can keep weekly full system backup to restore from.

**I am not sys admin so not sure is there anything i should keep in my maintenance plan like some sort of keys or something?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, the system state backup will hold the AD database, certificate store, DHCP setting, etc.  You'll probably need to backup the zone files for the DNS server.

You should really look at getting a second machine to use as a second domain controller so that if/when the first one fails your users can keep working while you fix the problem.

Comment: +1 for a second AD machine. 2 machines is bare minimum for AD

Comment: +1 for that Second AD. It's not fun when you only have one AD and it dies. Backups are nice but redunancy is best.

Comment: What use is active directory if you don't have another controller to replicate to?